# decompositions of a representation

Tags: representation-theory

I am reading J.P Serre's book on Linear representations of finite groups. In chapter 2.6 it states:

> Let $\rho: G \rightarrow GL(V)$ be a linear representation of $G$. We are going to define a direct sum decomposition of $V$ which is "coarser" than the decomposition into irreducible representations, but which has the advantage of being $unique$.

Now what does it mean by "coarser" in this context? I believe it means the former is less powerful than the latter, correct?

Answer (score 2):

It means that each piece of the former decomposition (that is, the decomposition into irreducible representations) will be part of some piece of the new decomposition.

Comment: but this decomposition will not be unique, correct?

Comment: I can't answer that question, since I don't know which is the specific decomposition defined by Serre.

Comment: ok. is it okay to say "less powerful" instead of "coarser"

Comment: I'd think "less powerful" is a terrible term.

Comment: @kimchilover I agree.

Comment: Surely this is what it means. @A.E Imagine that you and I are given the task of decomposing $V$. Imagine that there exists a subspace $W$ where $G$ acts trivially. Serre would expect both of us to identify the same subspace $W$. But he would not be surprised to see us split $W$ into a sum of irreducibles in different ways (unless, per chance, $\dim W<2$), because any way of writing $W$ as a direct sum of vector spaces would also be a decomposition into irreducible modules. That's pretty much what he is saying.

Comment: (cont'd) The "coarser" description of $V$ in terms of components like $W$ we would agree on, but we might use different "finer" decompositions into irreducible summands. The same thing happens with parts other than the one acted on trivially, but it is easier to see in the case of $W$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I appreciate your comments, very useful.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, sorry for the late response but as I am re-reading this chapter again, I need to refresh my memory aha. So decomposing V into irreducible sums is unique however the former need not be, correct?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen hence is "weaker" another appropriate word?